# FairPlay DRM configuration for iOS and Safari ( failed to load video)

Tags: ios, safari, drm, fairplay, shaka

I have a problem in fairplay drm + hls with safari (i used shaka player),
it fails at loading some contents .
but sometimes after reloading page it works .
Many thanks ,[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would e very unusual for a DRM server to respond with a valid license if it refused initially, just because it got multiple requests.

Looking at your screenshot above (it does not look like the usual safari inspector network tab?), it looks like the issue is actually with the file '...audio-en-us-mp4a.m3u8'. This is a HLS index file and assuming the screenshot is of network traffic it seems to be showing an error receiving this file, so this and any caching of this file are probably the best place to look for the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is even possible to use shaka player for safari iOS + HLS + FairPlay? Dont you need native player?